# 'Type does not name a type' when such type is the same name as of a data member of the class

Tags: c++

I have the following fictional class

**Header file**

```cpp
struct WidgetWrapper
{
  struct SubWidget
  {
    ...
    SubWidget& operator=(const SubWidget& rhs);
    ...
  };

  SubWidget SubWidget;
};
```

**Implementation file**

```cpp
...

WidgetWrapper::SubWidget& WidgetWrapper::SubWidget::operator=(const SubWidget& rhs)  // <--- error shown at this line
{
  ...
}

...
```

Such error shown is as follows

> error: `SubWidget` in `struct WidgetWrapper` does not name a type

I compiled on Linux 22.04 with GCC version 9.5.

Anyhow if I move the implementation of such `operator=` to be inlined at header file. Then there is no problem.

So

- Why compiler is not able to determine that such `SubWidget` is actually the type in this circumstance?
- Is there any possibility that I can implement it in the implementation file thus avoid such compilation error?

Comment: `SubWidget SubWidget;` Writing such code might interfere with future employability of the author.

Comment: to the first question: `int int;` according to you, that should work.

Comment: @Raildex That's also good example to see the direct point.

Comment: @Raildex `int int;` is slightly different case. You need `SubWidget` to be nested within `WidgetWrapper` for `SubWidget SubWidget;` to be ok. It doesnt work with non-nested classes, nor with `int int`: https://godbolt.org/z/oq8av9o8j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `struct` keyword to disambiguate:

```
struct WidgetWrapper
{
  struct SubWidget
  {
    SubWidget& operator=(const SubWidget& rhs);
  };

  SubWidget SubWidget;
};


struct WidgetWrapper::SubWidget& WidgetWrapper::SubWidget::operator=(const SubWidget& rhs) 
{
    return {};
}
```

Though, it is recommended not to end up in this situation in the first place by choosing appropriate names. Most naming conventions make it impossible to end up in this situation by using distinct conventions for members and types.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution works.
Asides for my first question, if it possible and not too much effort, could you hint/link me to the standard, or if you can give me reason why it cannot do such thing?

Comment: @haxpor tbh I dont know where this is specified, https://eel.is/c++draft/. Though, I mean there are two possibilities, you want one, c++ chose the other: https://godbolt.org/z/f61c85hM9. It could be the other way around, but then how would you pick the member?!?

Comment: @haxpor "why it cannot do such thing?" it is the compiler? It could but it doesnt.